# Rails 4 - Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm trying to figure out how to write scopes in rails 4.

I have a project model. I use statesman for states and have a state called :publish.

In my projects model, I want to write a scope that gets all projects in state publish.

I'm trying:

```
scope :published, ->{ where(projects.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)) }
scope :published, ->{ where(project.state_machine.in_state?(:publish)) }
```

I don't understand how to write scopes. The rails guides confuse me. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: could u provide some more code of your model? how do u include Statesman gem? what is the name of the column you use for state storage?

Comment: class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries

Comment: that's still not enough. are you sure you want to write your own scope? Statesman provides some built-in scopes to get elements in a supplied state, would it fit your needs?

Comment: I already have this in my projects model. But I can't use current state in my model to write a scope that picks out some states to add together as those which should be shown in the view: delegate :can_transition_to?, :transition_to!, :transition_to, :current_state,
           to: :state_machine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
class Project

  scope :published, -> { where(state: :publish)
```

Comment: No - that and all variations (current_state, in_state? don't work either. Thanks anyway